# why string is greater or less than the integer?

Tags: php

I am not able to get it that why the statement gets true both the times.?

```
$hello="foo";
     if($hello<=6){
        echo "yes\n";
     }
     if ($hello>=0) {
        echo "ohh yess!";
     }
```

it outputs

```
yes
ohh yess!
```

I do know this is illegal comparison between integer and string,but why after all it gets true.

Comment: It takes $hello as zero

Comment: It's not illegal; PHP has well-defined rules for this comparison. After all, you would expect `"5" < 6` to be true.

Comment: If it was illegal, you'd get an error message. Effectively, PHP is trying to convert `foo` to a number, and since there are no digits at the start, it's being cast to 0. See the man page on type juggling: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: so it takes $hello as zero while comparison only?

Comment: use === OR >== to get the actual result. because of week variable type and casting PHP behaves like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) says:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. **Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).**

In this case, the string `foo` evaluates to zero when the comparison is done and both the `if` conditions will hence evaluate to `TRUE`.

Effectively, you'll be doing:

```
if(0 <= 6) {
    echo "yes\n";
}

if (0 >= 0) {
    echo "ohh yess!";
}
```

Use `===` operator if you want to make sure the variable types are also taken into consideration.

Comment: ok.meaning to say that if $hello="4s" it will take it as 4 while comparison?

Answer (score 8):

This is because of [type juggling in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). So  `"foo"` evaluates to zero because it is converted to an integer. If you use the the identical operator (`===`) type conversions are not done so `"foo"` is treated a literal string and your statement will then evaluate to false.

Comment: I'm saying $hello is converted to 0 before the comparisons are made. That's why they are seeing those results.

Answer (score -1):

Currently it is checking `if $hello exist` and in both cases it is true.May be you want this

```
$hello="foo";
     if(strlen($hello)<=6){
        echo "yes\n";
     }
     if (strlen($hello)>=0) {
        echo "ohh yess!";
     }
```